# Building replacement 9.6 V NiCD battery pack for AN/ARM-186 aviation navigation system

Tags: batteries, parallel, nicd-battery

I bought an AN/ARM-186 aviation navigation systems tester made by Rockwell Collins, but it used two 9.6 V NiCD battery packs and the last ones it had were thrown away. I have been unable to find old ones to rebuild with new cells so I have to build my own. I am planning on using 16 1.2 V 1.1 A-h cells in two series configurations, since the unit required + and - dc power, separately. I will 3D-print the battery case in ABS, since it's two simple 5.9" x 1/5" x the height of the batteries.

How should each of the two 8-cell groups be configured for 9.6v V total?

Do I need some kind of BMS or other hardware between the charger and the cells to protect them during charging?

I plan to adapt a garden variety 9.6 V NiCD battery charger. I am planning to use nickel-plated copper strips to connect the terminals.

Comment: Do you have schematics or service manual for the device or the battery packs? It may reveal what is expected on the pack side and what isn't.

Comment: Energizer has stopped making Ni-Cad batteries many years ago and replaced them with much better Ni-NH with the same voltage as Ni-Cad. The AA size Ni-MH battery has a capacity of 2300mAh then charging from your old charger will take a little longer but a discharge will last more than double the time from an old Ni-Cad battery. Your batteries were in series and charged from 24V, not 9.6V total. Batteries in series usually have identical draining current so a BMS is not needed, the original 24V charger can be used.

Comment: The batteries are about 1.2V nominal each so it sounds like you just have a center tapped string of 16 cells. You might want to disconnect them during charging.

Comment: The manual just says two 9.6v battery packs. No schematics have been found and I've searched in dozens of locations and vendors.

Not interested in using a different battery chemistry, otherwise I would have put that into the question. The original charger is not a 24v charger. 

@SpehroPefhany What do you mean by "center tapped string of 16 cells"? Why 16 when 8 will do?

Comment: @JuanJimenez See the schematic below. I am taking the number of cells from your statement that the circuit requires +/-9.6. If it requires +9.6 and 0V then you don't need the right-hand half.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnNfpn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In general the current draw of a circuit like that will not be the same from the + and - supplies, so you may wish to have one charger for each half, and to disconnect the battery when charging. There also must be no common ground on the two chargers, obviously, since the + and - must be connected together for charging. Or perhaps you could charge half the battery at a time with one charger if that met your needs.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it is exactly what I need. I'll come back with comments once I test it on the unit.